# L2tp/IPSEC vs pure IPSEC

Tags: ipsec, l2tp

So, I was reading about the L2TP protocol and I understand what it basically does. But I fail to see why it would be preferred over pure IPSEC(VPN). VPN already provides end-to-end encryption between the gateway and my PC then why would I add more headers to the encapsulated packet and increase my bandwidth? Even if I am connecting one enterprise network located in two locations, can't we still do it via a pure VPN connection?

I think I am missing something very basic here. Can someone point it out! Thanks a lot.

-koundi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [same question was asked on the Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/144528/why-use-l2tp-ipsec-insted-of-just-ipsec/144533#144533).  Here's my answer to that question:

> L2TP/IPSec uses IPsec to protect the L2TP tunnel. So the real question
>   is, why use L2TP?
>
> Layer two tunneling protocol, as the name implies, provides a layer 2
>   link over an arbitrary L3 network. So, for example, if you needed to
>   have a single VLAN appear in two locations (two data centers, for
>   example), you can use L2TP to connect them together and appear as one
>   logical VLAN/subnet, even though there is an arbitrary L3 network
>   between them (like the Internet). Since you probably don't want your
>   data center traffic traversing the Internet unprotected, you use IPSec
>   to keep your traffic confidential.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just want to know one more thing. Is this the only uses case? Also why not just encapsulate the ethernet frame(or any other layer 2 protocol for that matter) instead of adding more headers?? As I understand the tunnel and session need to be created for l2tp tunel and the payload in a l2tp data message would be a ethernet frame